# Updating state within React Hook Form

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I have a very simple submit form that I'm using React-hook-form to implement and I'm running into this strange issue where the global state isn't updated when I submit the first time, but it works the second time. Here's my code:

```
export default function Enter() {
    const { register, handleSubmit, watch, formState: { errors } } = useForm();
    const { state, dispatch } = useContext(Store)

    const onSubmit = (data) => {

        console.log('sending user: ', data.username)
        dispatch({
            type: 'SET_PLAYER',
            payload: data.username
        })
        console.log('UPDATED CLIENT STATE: ', state)
    }

    return (
    <>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <p>Enter your name to join lobby</p>
            <input {...register("username", { required: true })} />
            {errors.exampleRequired && <span>This field is required</span>}
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </>
    );
}
```

Here's a picture of how state appears to be lagging behind, essentially:

[image]

Comment: The state is not able to be refreshed mid-function. React takes the function and executes it. After it it then refreshes the rest of the state. So within `onSubmit` after your `dispatch` function call I would not expect the `state` to be including the new state you just sent it as you're still in the same function. Use `data` instead within the same function.

Answer (score 0):

Dominik's comment was spot-on. Even though updates to state are synchronous, state updates in between function refreshes so you should use data within the function and if you need to do something after that updates, then use `useEffect` and wait for the state change.